# How to add list of fragment into DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with DialogFragment

For example I have a list of Fragment and I want to add all this fragment into DialogFragment and alert whenever the user Click on a button, Do anyone have any idea

I try this on this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
public static class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ScrollView scroller = new ScrollView(getActivity());
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        int padding = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                4, getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        text.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        scroller.addView(text);
        text.setText(Shakespeare.DIALOGUE[getShownIndex()]);
        return scroller;
    }
}
```

Please help :)